# Como ter a opção de conectar a mais de um banco de dados na minha aplicação C# Visual Studio pelo app.config

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, conexão, visual-studio-2017

Tenho uma aplicação em C# que fiz no Visual Studio. Essa aplicação conecta a um banco de dados Sql Server. Gostaria de colocar no meu login uma opção em forma de lista para escolher outro banco caso eu tenha mais de um em minha aplicação. Por exemplo: um ctrl+c ctrl+v do mesmo banco mas de duas empresas diferentes. Estou usando o app.config com a string semelhante a esta

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MinhaStringDeConexao"
       connectionString="Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=MinhaDb; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
       providerName="SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Como eu faço para colocar mais conexões ai dentro e como eu faço para recupera-las no meu form principal depois do login. Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: só colocar outra linha dentro do connectionStrings uai, aí acessa cada conexao pelo atributo name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em vez de adicionar variáveis, Aconselho seriamente a criar uma classe! Mais pratico e ocupa menos espaço.

assim:

```
public class MyDatabaseConnection {
    public MyDatabaseConnection(string connectionString) {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
        // criar uma conexa à bd
    }
    // alguns metodos para fazer a query á BD
    public void execute(string query) { }
}
```

Assim fica mais facil de adicionar, seja 1,2,3 ou mais conexões

```
MyDatabaseConnection con1 = new MyDatabaseConnection("Server=etc_etc_bd");
MyDatabaseConnection con2 = new MyDatabaseConnection("Server=dois_bd");
MyDatabaseConnection con3 = new MyDatabaseConnection("Server=um_bd");
```

E executar a Query em cada um (QUERY = PERGUNTA)

```
MyDatabaseConnection[] cons = new MyDatabaseConnection[]{ con1, con2, con3 };
foreach (MyDatabaseConnection con in cons) {
    con.execute(someSqlCommandText);
}
```

Comment: Não sou muito experiente em C# ainda, onde eu crio essa classe? No form principal? como eu faço para chama-la em outros forms?